# How to count frequency of multiple items in a list and print relative frequencies

Tags: python, string, list, count

Given two lists, I need to count the frequency of the items in one list as they are found in the other list; and place the relative frequencies of each item inside `frequencyList` (where the
frequency of `searchFor[0]` is stored in `frequencyList[0]`)

I am unable to import anything

```py
textList=['a','b','a','c',...]    
searchFor=['a','b']   
frequencyList=[2,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[textList.count(i) for i in searchFor]
```

Or?

```
list(map(textList.count, searchFor))
```

Comment: The question should be closed but the answer is nice

Comment: thats O(m*n). It can be solved in one pass over `textList`

Comment: Sorry!!! Your solution works, but it appears that I have misunderstood what resources I have! I am given two lists, wordList and frequencyList, where the frequency of an item in wordList is represented in the same index as frequencyList. I am supposed to find the items listed in searchFor inside of wordList and then draw their frequency from frequencyList and print out the resulting number into an entirely new list.

Comment: @JackKrebs What's teh desired output?

Comment: a new list that would say the frequency of only the words inside of the searchFor list. For example: newList=['1','4','1','5',...]          I think I can figure out the rest of the code from this point :)

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^ the ouput I really need is to place both searchFor and newList in a .txt document, but I've got that locked down.   I could still use your help on actually acquiring those lists :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is quite compact and very pythonic but this is an alternate solution that is *slightly* more efficient as it only requires one pass over the input list.

```
textList=['a','b','a','c']
output_dict = {}

for i in textList:
    try:
        output_dict[i] = d[i] + 1
    except:
        output_dict[i] = 1

print(output_dict['a'])
```

Comment: He would want to filter multiple keys from `output_dict`, also you could use `setdefault` or `defaultdict`, or better with `Counter`.

Comment: Sorry!!! Your solution works, but it appears that I have misunderstood what resources I have! I am given two lists, wordList and frequencyList, where the frequency of an item in wordList is represented in the same index as frequencyList. I am supposed to find the items listed in searchFor inside of wordList and then draw their frequency from frequencyList and print out the resulting number into an entirely new list.